# Fill sparse matrix with sapply in R

Tags: r, matrix, sapply

Say `X` is a large sparse matrix, where every row has only one entry different from zero. I have a vector `pos` with the locations of the columns where this nonzero element goes. To fill the matrix, the following loop works:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(X)) {
    X[row, pos[row]] <- 1
}
```

Is there a way to do this without a loop, perhaps using `sapply`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might take a look at the `sparseMatrix` function from Matrix:

```
> library(Matrix)
> (pos = sample(1:7))
[1] 5 1 6 4 7 2 3
> sparseMatrix(1:7, pos)
7 x 7 sparse Matrix of class "ngCMatrix"

[1,] . . . . | . .
[2,] | . . . . . .
[3,] . . . . . | .
[4,] . . . | . . .
[5,] . . . . . . |
[6,] . | . . . . .
[7,] . . | . . . .
```

The funcions from package Matrix take some using to, but they provide tons of benefits when working with sparse matrices.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Since `X` is not necessarily a square matrix, I used `X <- sparseMatrix(i = 1:n, j = pos, x = 1)`, where `n` is the number of rows.